# private key ssh doesn't work for user jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh-keys

I have scripts that clone code from github via SSH protocol. I added my SSH key to the ssh-agent for all users (my account, root, jenkins). I tested executing the script, it worked fine. But it didn't work when I executed script by Jenkins. I got the message

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

Could you please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permissions on your SSH folder/files?

As explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder), you should have:

```
700 (drwx------) on the .ssh folder
644 (-rw-r--r--) on the public key (*.pub)
600 (-rw-------) on the private key (id_rsa) + the authorized_keys file
```